# Bug-tracking system that integrates with Visual Studio 2010 with online-support?

Tags: visual-studio, bug-tracking

Where can I find a bug-tracking system that integrates with Visual Studio 2010 as an addin, and supports online support (so that anonymous people can add bugs to the buglist)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up building my own system based on a database and a webserver. I then created a Visual Studio Package (add-in) through the Visual Studio 2010 SDK for managing bugs that were synced live from the website.

Way better for my needs, and only took 1 week of development.

Answer (score 3):

You could use TFS and write a simple web frontend utilizing the TFS webservices. Perhaps there are bugtrackers that support TFS integration.

Unfortunately, I do not know of other solutions integrated into VS.

Comment: Very useful indeed. I didn't know TFS had so-called webservices. I'll look into that more. However, since I my project is not open source (to host on Codeplex TFS servers) and my budget is very limited since I am a startup, a free or cheaper solution would be much better.